# How to make Vert.x JWTAuthHandler only injects the User object but not rejecting unauthorized request?

Tags: vert.x

My API has different logic based on the user whether provides authorization or not. If I just write `router.route(...).handler(Handler)` , the `RoutingContext.user()` always returns null even the request provides authorization, but if I write `router.route(...).handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt)); router.route(...).handler(Handler)` , any request without authorization is immediately rejected with unauthorized response without running my API logic. How can I just let it inject the user object if authorization is provided, but not reject the request?

Answer (score 0):

The `JWTHandler` will stop your execution if the `Authorization` header contains an invalid token or no token at all is present. Allowing it to continue would introduce a security flaw, as it means any token, valid or fake, would be accepted.

I can imagine you may want to recover in some error states, in that case there are is a way to handle this. For example:

```
router.route()
  .handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JWTAuthOptions())))
  .failureHandler(ctx -> {
    // recover and continue
    ctx.setUser(User.create(new JsonObject().put("name", "paulo")));
    ctx.reroute(ctx.normalizedPath());
  });

router.route()
  .handler(RoutingContext::end);
```

In your recovery `failureHandler` you must set your own `User` object and call a reroute, which will restart the request. Given that there is already a `User` in the context, the second time, the `JWTAuthHandler` will skip the execution and the next handler that just ends the request completes with status code `200` (`OK`)

Comment: E.g. if I want to implement the logic that, if user provides an authorization, it adds the query to the user history, otherwise it just responses the result, what is the best way to implement it?